# Biblatex, authoryear-comp, "and" instead of comma separator

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the `authoryear-comp` style with `biblatex`. However, instead of being separated by a comma, I would like the years to be separated by `and`.

Right now,`\footcite`gives this result:

[image]

But I would like it took look something like this:

> A and B 1995 and 1998.

I tried to `\renewbibmacro` but failed miserably.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
       author = {A and B},
       title = {Title},
       journal = {American Journal of Political Science},
       year = {1995},
       type = {Journal Article}
    }

@article{b,
       author = {A and B},
       title = {Title},
       journal = {American Journal of Political Science},
       year = {1998}
    }
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\footcite{a,b}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\space\bibsstring{and}\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
       author = {A and B},
       title = {Title},
       journal = {American Journal of Political Science},
       year = {1995},
       type = {Journal Article}
    }

@article{b,
       author = {A and B},
       title = {Title},
       journal = {American Journal of Political Science},
       year = {1998}
    }
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\footcite{a,b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that your definition introduces spurious double-spaces after the "and", I'd use `biblatex`'s bibstrings and would go with `\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}`. Of course it would be even nicer if we could detect if we are at the last year in a list and have a comma for all other years.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your comment! I was just browsing the documentation to find this command.